# differences between graphs and MYSQL database in facebook?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, graph, relational-database

I can't understand where facebook uses really mysql:

All the Database can be seen as a graph:

```
Account - Like -> Comment
Account <- friend -> Account2
Account - Like -> Link
```

And what is stored in MySQL?

the text of the posts and notes?

Have facebook all these entities ( account, post, comment ) in its graph DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I assume that everything You mentioned is stored in MySQL. Every piece of data that is subject to change, including:

- Users
- Posts
- Comments
- Information about uploaded pictures (but not pictures themselves)
- Likes
- Data about users logging in
- Ads
- Data about users liking / not liking ads
- User settings

etc.

Any data that is subject to change needs to be saved in database for indexing and fast access. Filesystem is fine if You want to write-only data, for example logging. Or if You only need to access the whole data at once, not parts of it.

But if You need data to be structured and ready to be accessed quickly, then You need to use a database. You may want to read about binary trees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree

About Facebook: If I had to guess, I would say that there are probably hundreds of more databases. I don't have access to their servers, so I can't really comment on that :) But as another example, if You install WordPress, then it creates 11 different tables. http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

PS. There is no reason facebook should use MySQL, though. There are lot of different databases out there.

**EDIT** Thanks for pointing out that I misunderstood Your question.

Lets take this case: Account <- friend -> Account2

As said before, they have table like "Users".

Users table will have columns:

- ID (It has PRIMARY KEY. This is meant to give unique ID to each row.)
- Username (Text field with some length, for example 64 characters)
- ...And many more...

Now there will be table "Friends". It will have fields:

- ID (again, PRIMARY KEY)
- Person1
- Person2

Both fields Person1 and Person2 will be integers pointing to ID in table "users".

So if table users has three rows:

```
ID  Username
1   rodi
2   rauni
3   superman
```

Then table "Friends" would be for example:

```
ID Person1 Person2
1  1       2
2  2       1
3  1       3
4  3       1
```

Here row 1 means "rodi is friend with rauni" and row 2 means that "rauni is friend with rodi". This is redundant, but I wanted to keep example simple.

Here is good tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqltables.php
There are many pages there, just keep clicking Next to skip what You already know (I don't know how much You already know)

This is about joining info from two tables: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

You could use this to select all rodi's friends from our two tables in one query.

Comment: ok, but, where do you store all the edges as "Account - Like -> Link" or "Account <- friend -> Account2"?

Comment: That's a good and detailed explanation. I would upvote you for your edit, if I didn't already upvote your original answer. So will someone give him another upvote?